# Tips on surviving a biome dungeon?

Tags: starbound

I'm playing as an Avian character, and I stumbled upon an Avian dungeon. I would have assumed that the creatures within would have thought me friendly (since I'm the same race), but that's apparently not the case.

I've got tier 2 Avian armor at the moment, and a pretty nice rocket launcher, but the enemies inside always destroy me (their weapons are pretty powerful). Are there any basic strategies for surviving dungeons as an early-level character?

Comment: don't get hit by the weapons that destroy you

Comment: They're *supposed* to be hard. If you're not ready for them then don't go in.

Comment: What's the planet surface biome?

Comment: What? People from the same race killing each other? Who would've thought! :P